Why loading AutoTokenizer takes so much RAM?
I was measuring the RAM that is used by my script and I was surprised that it takes about 300Mb of RAM, while the tokenizer file itself is about 9MB. Why is that?
I tried:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def load_tokenizer():
    path = "sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2" 
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(path)

    return tokenizer

load_tokenizer()

Output:
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     4    377.4 MiB    377.4 MiB           1   @profile
     5                                         def load_tokenizer():
     6    377.4 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       path = "sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2" 
     7    676.6 MiB    299.2 MiB           1       tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(path)
     8                                             
     9                                         
    10    676.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return tokenizer


it is not the AutoTokenizer issue. BertTokenizerFast shows same memory usage.
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     5    406.1 MiB    406.1 MiB           1   @profile
     6                                         def load_tokenizer():
     7    406.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       path = "sentence-transformers/paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2" 
     8    708.3 MiB    302.2 MiB           1       tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(path)

Most of the RAM use increment comes from the loading lines:
tokenizer_file_handle = json.load(tokenizer_file_handle)
and
fast_tokenizer = TokenizerFast.from_file(fast_tokenizer_file)
Well, this is Python, there is quite much written about why objects take much space in RAM. Here are a few inks at SO:

Python - size of object in memory vs. on disk
Why does a file stored as a dictionary take up much more space than file
Find out how much memory is being used by an object in Python

